# Weka ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, weka, classnotfoundexception

I'm attempting to install Weka, which I have installed into /weka directory. I set the CLASSPATH variable, but that shouldn't matter anyway because I'm using -cp.

I enter this into SSH:

> java -Xmx5G -cp /weka/weka.jar
>   weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader -dir /home/myuser/test >
>   /home/myuser/test.arff

And it spits out:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   weka/core/converters/TextDirectoryLoader Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266) Could not find the main class: weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader.
>   Program will exit.

What wrong? There is no "weka/core/converters/TextDirectoryLoader" because its all stored in weka.jar, which is where it should be looking.

My Java version:

> java version "1.6.0_20" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.10)
>   (rhel-1.23.1.9.10.el5_7-x86_64) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build
>   19.0-b09, mixed mode)

I just downloaded Weka today from the link on their downloads page, so there shouldn't be anything wrong with it.

Now I know that this would normally be because it can't find weka.jar, but I promise you that it is right there at: /weka/weka.jar. And I can also promise that both the /weka directory and weka.jar have execute permissions.

Please help!

Comment: It's non-existent! I decided to go ahead and unpack the jar file and there is no weka/core/converters/TextDirectoryLoader.class! What happened there? Everyone else seems to have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just downloading and running the .jar works for me:

```
carsten@dallas:~$ java -Xmx5G -cp /tmp/weka-3-6-5/weka.jar weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader

Usage:
  TextDirectoryLoader [options]

Options:
...
```

as well as `java -jar /tmp/weka-3-6-5/weka.jar`, which opens some GUI tool.

You sure that you installed Weka on the server you SSH into?

Comment: Note: I don't have the exact same version of OpenJDK running:
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.9) (6b20-1.9.9-0ubuntu1~10.10.2)

Comment: Funny, because I just tested weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector and it loads fine. It's only weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader that appears to be invisible.

Comment: Is there any (even microscopically small) possibility of a typo in the path to that .jar? Mayhaps some characters upper case?

Or a version problem? I downloaded the latest version from SF, but maybe you got an older version on the server lacking weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader...

Comment: You could try `jar tf /weka/weka.jar | grep TextDirectoryLoader` to see if the class is in the .jar.

Comment: Which version did you download from the Weka site? The snapshot or the stable? Linux?

Comment: Yes, it was not in there. Missing in fact. I must have been stupid and downloaded the wrong version. Just reinstalled with the latest snapshot and it works a treat! Thansk!

Comment: The one featured on the SF project page: http://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/latest/download?_test=goal
(It ended up downloading weka-3-6-5.zip.) Seems like an OS independent version to me.

Answer (score 0):

I happened the same to me in Mac OS when I used the jar released in the dmg packaged.

Instead of that one, I imported the jar file under:

```
Applications/Weka/Resources/java/weka.jar
```

To get it you have to:

1. go to Applications
2. right click over weka-3-x-x
3. Show package content
4. go to /Resources/java/weka.jar
5. import that one jar into your classpath